# Font sizes are different for IE8 and Firefox how come

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, fonts, font-size

I am using this font

```
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:regular,bold&v1' rel='stylesheet'
    type='text/css' />
```

But the render is different for internet explorer and firefox. It works correctly at firefox, chrome, opera but it shows bigger for internet explorer 8. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure it is stock IE8 and not customised in any way? (Speculation: you have higher DPI on your monitor and IE8 respects that whereas FF/Chrome may not)

Comment: IE uses a different rendering engine. It should really come as no surprise that font sizes are slightly different. Remember that you're designing for the web, not print media. You don't get absolute control over every pixel. No matter what you do, I can always change the default font size in my browser.

Comment: First make sure your website isn't being rendered in quirks mode. Link to your website would help solving your problem.

Comment: web site url : http://www.monstermmorpg.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) spreadsheet first.

Comment: not even an option. the center feature removed. also background is not displayed. text is different now and many other problems.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Use it *first* i.e. before any other styles. Any other problems beyond that are probably from fragile markup.